# Getting Unique result set from two table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I m new to SQL Server, please help me with the solution to following problem.

I have two tables which have the following columns:

- `Table-A` only has one column with data like (`A, B, C, D`)
- `Table-B` is a temporary table which can contain (`B, B, C, C, E, E, F, G`)

I need to insert contents of table B into table A.

Conditions are

1. if table A already contains any alphabet in B then that alphabet should be ignored.
2. Only a unique alphabet needs to be inserted into table A. i.e. Only one E can be inserted from two set of E and
3. if F and G also needs to be inserted.

How can I possibly solve this problem?

Thanking you in advance....

Comment: Please add sample data and results demonstrating exactly how your conditions should function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column)
SELECT DISTINCT tt.Column 
FROM TempTab tt
WHERE tt.Column NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Column FROM Table)
```

Here is the [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/493c2/1) with this query.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO A(col) 
 (SELECT distinct col from B 
    minus 
  (SELECT distinct col FROM A INTERSECT SELECT distinct col FROM B))
```